# Avoid Url to be treated as hyperlinks in Rails Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, mailer

I'm sending a mailer to users that includes a link to their created post.

This link should be for copying and pasting only, however it delivers automatically as a blue underlined hyperlink.
Any suggestions?

Thanks

```
<td width="440" height="50" bgcolor="#f5f5f5" style="border:1px solid #e3e3e3; display: block; margin:40px auto;">
  <div style="color:#666f67; font-size:16px; font-weight: 400; font-family:sans-serif; text-decoration: none; display:block; text-align:center; padding: 16px;">
        url
  </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Can you post your email template? For email templates you have to use inline styling

Comment: Adding inline html above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bootstrap library is not included in emails as it would be in regular views. If you need to format emails, you'll have to do it inline. For example:

```
<a href="" style="text-decoration: none; color: green">hello</a>
```

Checkout Mailchimp, they have great resources on how to create email templates.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, Correction, I'm mimicking the well class, all inline, in the html. the problem is that its a hyperlink automatically, which i dont want

Comment: Ok. I think your email client interprets the url as a link even though you did not markup a `<a>` tag. Try creating a proper `<a>`, style it inline and disable it. This way, you get the control, it's not clickable, the user can copy and paste. Is that's what you want? `<a href="#" style="color: black; text-decoration: none; pointer-events: none">your-url</a>`

Comment: Awesome! So simple really! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found another way for future reference, by placing it inside an input field "readonly."

```
<input type="text" value="www.mylink.com" readonly>
```